# widget initialLayout not displaying - android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, widget

My application widgets work on my phone and my friends' devices too.
But some user on google play complaint about widgets not working.

Please help me in finding out what is going wrong?

Customer Complaints:

*The widgets for this app don't work. No matter what size I try. Not worth the money. I've got free apps that work right on my Sasmsung galaxy Note

*Can I get refund widget doesn't work

I replied: please confirm is the widget having a black transparent box(check screenshot this is initialLayout) or is it completely transparent.

Customer Reply: Ok I tried that and it is still completely transparent
[image: initialLayout of widget without any update]

I used simple code for update

```
try {
  ComponentName Widget =
  new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider2x2.class);
  AppWidgetManager wman =   AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
  wman.updateAppWidget(Widget, remoteView);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

manifest code

```
<receiver
  android:name=".WidgetProvider4x3"
  android:label="Widget(4x3)" >
  <intent-filter>
  <action   android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
  android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
  android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo4x3" />
</receiver>
```

widgetinfo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="250dp"
  android:minHeight="180dp"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout4x3" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

this is all i did, hope some one can point me to right direction

*The initial Layout is the semi-transparent black box, but customer said completely transparent widget. So is this possible that widget is not displaying the initialLayout?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask customer to try a different home-screen/Launcher.

If its still the same:

1. the `RemoteViews` you are supplying are failing to be inflated.
2. the widget provider does not complete its update job well.
3. there's nothing to display.

Launcher will often place a `loading..` screen if widget takes too much time to inflate.

Comment: I will ask the customer.
Should i check my onUpdate function, does this line mean anything in this relation :-- super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
i commented this line because i update the widget manually

Comment: @Diljeet Never skip super calls unless you are sure it will do something you don't want.

Comment: Well the customers only complaints but they don't reply to me, so sorry i can't mark the answer as correct. I will release the new update soon and if there wont be any complaints then i will mark the answer as correct.
Thanks for all your replies